# Unexpected behavior from path.combine

Tags: c#, .net

Given the code:

```
   string p = @"C:\Users\Brian";
   string p2 = @"\bin\Debug";
   string result = Path.Combine(p, p2);//result: \bin\Debug
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I expect to see a result of:

```
  C:\Users\Brian\bin\Debug
```

However the result is

```
  \bin\Debug
```

If I initialize `p2 = @"bin\Debug";`

Then the result is as expected.  Looking at MSDN this appears to work as designed:

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start
>   with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a
>   concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator
>   character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

IMO, it makes far more sense in .NET to exclude `\` as a root.  AFAIK, this is not a valid root on any windows OS (`\\` can be).  I could then combine partial paths without concern over whether a partial path begins with a `\`.

Why is this method designed to consider a single `\` a root?

Comment: Did you try cd \ or dir \?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this method designed to consider a single \ a root?

Because it *is* a root as far as other operations are concerned. For example, on the command prompt:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>dir \
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is C058-6ADE

 Directory of c:\
```

Or from other file operations in .NET:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\Users\Jon\Test\Test.cs");
        Console.WriteLine(lines.Length);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11
```

Or from Java:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path = "\\Users\\Jon\\Test\\Test.java";
        // Just to prove that the double backslashes are language escapes...
        System.out.println(path);

        // Obviously we'd normally clean stuff up...
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(stream, "utf-8"));
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\Users\Jon\Test\Test.java
import java.io.*;
```

I dare say the same would be true from native code.

So, where *doesn't* Windows allow you to start a path with a "\" to root it within the current drive?

> Why is this method designed to consider a single \ a root?

I think the bigger question is why you started what you wanted to be a *relative* path with a `\`.